# Fix for tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified when running a remote shell script using SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-access, xterm, tput

I have a nodetimecheck.sh file on a server which has a command like this

```
echo
tput setaf 2; echo -n " What is my node's local time: "; tput setaf 7; date
```

When I login to my server with SSH and execute ./nodetimecheck.sh it displays properly.

However, if I try to execute the command from my local machine via ssh like this

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/privkey username@serverip ./nodetimecheck.sh`

It does display the time, but there is a nagging message

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Local machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Remote server on GCP running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as follows. Supply the TERM=xterm as part of the ssh command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/privkey username@serverip TERM=xterm ./nodetimecheck.sh
```

Comment: This would only "work" if you are connecting from a terminal where `TERM` is not set, and has no effect on the other end of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute `tput` command when there's no TTY available.

A real solution would check whether the command is executed in a real terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
# a wrapper that checks whether TTY is available
t_put () {
  tty -s && tput "$@"
}
echo 
t_put setaf 2; echo -n " What is my node's local time: "; t_put setaf 7; date
```

Comment: not really: just having a TTY connection doesn't ensure that `TERM` is set.